# JavaScript Read, Process and Combine JSON from Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, json, filereader

I have very little clue when it comes to JavaScript, but I am looking to upload multiple JSON files, process them, convert them to text, combine them and then download to a single JS file.

I've managed to get this working fine for a single file but processing multiple files by passing contents as a variable from FileReader/FileReaderSync results is beyond my understanding.

**Upload Inputs:**
TestA.json => { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }
TestB.json => { "name":"Bob", "age":35, "car":"toyota"}

Processing: Arbitrary.... but lets just say add 5 to the ages

**Download / Output** JS file as follows:
`var TestA = { "name":"John", "age":35, "car":null }; var TestB = { "name":"Bob", "age":40, "car":"toyota"};`

This is what I have to process files but I can't figure out how to merge the outputs into a single file;

https://jsfiddle.net/simid/0d9mqn7y/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function encodeJSON (varJSON) {
            //do something to varJSON
        }
        
        function processFiles() {
                var filelist = document.getElementById('files').files;
                for(var i=0; i<filelist.length; i++) {
                    encodeFiles(filelist[i]);
                }
            }
        
        function encodeFiles(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function() {
                var JSONData = JSON.parse(reader.result);
                encodeJSON(JSONData);
                JSONData = 'var ' + file.name.split('.')[0] + ' = ' + JSON.stringify(JSONData) + ';' 
                var blob = new Blob([JSONData], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
                saveAs(blob, 'encoded.js');
            }
            reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>JSON inputs:</p>
    <p><input type="file" multiple id="files" onchange="processFiles()" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will fire `reader.readAsText()` as soon as the first file is processed, hence you only get the first file.

You can fix this by making a global variable outside your loop.

This should work, note the use of `let` in the `for` loop:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var JSONData = "";

      function encodeJSON(file, t) {
        JSONData += 'var ' + file.name.split('.')[0] + ' = ' + t.result + '\n';
      }

      function processFiles() {
        var filelist = document.getElementById('files').files;
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(e) {
            for(let i=0; i<filelist.length; i++) {
              encodeJSON(filelist[i], e.target)
          }
          var blob = new Blob([JSONData], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
          saveAs(blob, 'encoded.js');
        }
        reader.readAsText(filelist[0], 'UTF-8')
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>JSON inputs:</p>
    <p><input type="file" multiple id="files" onchange="processFiles()" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't want to trigger `saveAs` for every iteraton

Comment: The problem is that you are still only reading one file `filelist[0]`

Comment: No, it produces a combined file. you could call `reader.readAsText(filelist[filelist.length -1], 'UTF-8')` and it will have the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hugh. While it seems to work fine with the small JSON samples I have very large JSON files that need to be stored in a variable with `JSON.Parse` so they can be modified using some loops and logic. When i upload 2 files (1st one small, second large), the output seems to get confused and the JSON from the first file in the list seems to process twice. The resulting export has the 1st file twice?

Comment: Nice solution from @Endless

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of Response + async/await and some newer syntax can take you a long way without the need of using callbacks or the FileReader.

```
async function processFiles (evt) {
  // use object destructoring of evt.target 
  // instead of querying it from the DOM
  const { files } = evt.target
  let result = ''

  // using for..of loop instead
  for (const file of files) {
    // take advantage of the Response hack to convert
    // to json with the help of promises + await
    let json = await new Response(file).json()
    
    // modify json

    // append modified json to the result
    result += `var ${file.name.split('.')[0]} = ${json};\n` 
  }

  // save everything
  const blob = new Blob([JSONData], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"})
  saveAs(blob, 'encoded.js')
}
```

It would be possible to use JSON.parse(await [file.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text)) but why bother if you can get json from the response anyway and having more cross browser support?

Comment: Cheers for sending me down a rabbit hole. The newer syntax is foreign to me but i'm keen to understand it. Swapping out the JS in my page gives
 _Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined_ 
Could you give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: change `onchange="processFiles()"` -> `onchange="processFiles(event)"`

Comment: or add the event listener with js using `input.onchange = processFile`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I had to  `result += \`var ${file.name.split('.')[0]} = ${JSON.stringify(json)};\n\`` Now to go play around and figure out how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Thank you @Endless .. This is what i ended up with;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.2/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function encodeJSON (varJSON) {
        // do something to varJSON
    }

    async function processFiles (evt) {
        // use object destructoring of evt.target 
        // instead of querying it from the DOM
        const { files } = evt.target
        let result = ''

        // using for..of loop instead
        for (const file of files) {
            // take advantage of the Response hack to convert
            // to json with the help of promises + await
            let json = await new Response(file).json()
            
            // modify json
            encodeJSON(json);

            // append modified json to the result
            result += \`var ${file.name.split('.')[0]} = ${JSON.stringify(json)};\n\` 
        }

        // save everything
        const blob = new Blob([result], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"})
        saveAs(blob, 'encoded.js')
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>JSON inputs:</p>
    <p><input type="file" multiple id="files" onchange="processFiles(event)" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```